# I am trying to get semicolon to act as shift when held down but ; when tapped and colon when shift is down and also as end when CapsLock is held down

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, automation

This is the code I have tried in Karabiner-Elements.

The semicolon key sends semicolon when tapped ✔

When shift is held down and semicolon is tapped colon is sent ✔

While CapsLock is held down and semicolon is tapped end is sent ✔

While semicolon is held down shift should be activated ✖

```
{
  "global": {},
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Default",
      "complex_modifications": {
        "rules": [
          {
            "description": "CapsLock + Esc when tapped, set capslock_modifier variable when held",
            "search to jump to this point": "capscaps",
            "manipulators": [
              {
                "type": "basic",
                "from": {
                  "key_code": "caps_lock",
                  "modifiers": {
                    "optional": ["any"]
                  }
                },
                "to": [
                  {
                    "set_variable": {
                      "name": "capslock_modifier",
                      "value": 1
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "to_if_alone": [
                  {
                    "key_code": "escape"
                  }
                ],
                "to_after_key_up": [
                  {
                    "set_variable": {
                      "name": "capslock_modifier",
                      "value": 0
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "description": "Change semicolon to shift, colon, or end",
            "manipulators": [
              {
                "type": "basic",
                "from": {
                  "key_code": "semicolon",
                  ";modifiers": {
                    "optional": ["any"]
                  }
                },
                "parameters": {
                  "basic.to_if_alone_timeout_milliseconds": 250,
                  "basic.to_if_held_down_threshold_milliseconds": 250
                },
                "to_if_alone": [
                  {
                  "key_code": "semicolon"
                  }
                ],
                "to_if_held_down": [
                  {
                    "key_code": "right_shift",
                    "lazy": false
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "description": "Change semicolon to shift, colon, or end",
            "manipulators": [
              {
                "type": "basic",
                "from": {
                  "key_code": "semicolon",
                  "modifiers": {
                    "optional": ["any"]
                  }
                },
                "conditions": [
                  {
                    "type": "variable_if",
                    "name": "capslock_modifier",
                    "value": 1
                  }
                ],
                "to": [
                  {
                    "key_code": "end"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The end works and semicolon and colon worked. But it does not work as shift when held down.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: limited motion in my fingers so i try to use as few keys as possible

Comment: You might investigate adaptive keyboards, e.g., https://www.ucdenver.edu/centers/center-for-inclusive-design-and-engineering/community-engagement/colorado-assistive-technology-act-program/technology-and-transition-to-employment/alternative-keyboards, https://www.amazon.com/typing-keyboard-disabled/s?k=typing+keyboard+for+disabled+typing, https://www.amazon.com/one-handed-keyboard/s?k=one+handed+keyboard